Is there a way to force launched activities on Android to start in the current process?
I have an app that is using a background service to isolate a poorly behaved library. The service is run on a new process:
<service
    android:name="com.myapp.MyBackgroundService"
    android:exported="false"
    android:process=":isolation" />

This library is an AAR, and it includes its own manifest that gets merged with mine, that effectively has:
<activity
   android:name="com.badlibrary.TheirActivity"/>

I initialize their library in my service, and eventually it tries to launch their activity, but because their activity doesn't have an android:process it default's to the app's process, not the caller's process. The library uses a bunch of static state (I know, bad library, I didn't write it), so when their activity launches in the main process it crashes.
Ideally there would be a way to say in the service "any activities that get launched in this process default to running in this process." But is there any way to specify the process an activity launches in without modifying the manifest?

Have you tried using manifest merger rules to add android:process to that activity in your own manifest?

Interesting direction. I'd have to copy the entries out of their manifest and put them in my own with the android:process declaration I want, and then their entries would be discarded? Is there a less manual process that ensures I get updated when they change their manifest?

"and then their entries would be discarded?" -- you only need android:name and android:process. Everything else will be inherited (more or less) from their own manifest. "Is there a less manual process that ensures I get updated when they change their manifest?" -- um, write yourself a script or something to code-generate your manifest entries, maybe. There's no "have everything in this library go into this process" directive, if that's what you are asking.

This could work. I'm still hoping for a Java solution rather than a manifest one, but this is what I'll fall back on. Thank you.

"I'm still hoping for a Java solution rather than a manifest one" -- I am fairly confident that there is none.
